# datagridview in metro

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to create a datagridview in metro, likes in winform, with a header of datagridview, and I can select any row to edit or delete, how to design it? I know Grid can display data, but it couldn't let me to select anyrow, I've also reviewed gridview, but still didn't find how to realize it. I have a list of object, and I want to bind the list to the gridview, and I can also edit or delete any row of it, is it possible? Or there's other better design?

Comment: There is no built in DataGridView with similar features like Windows Forms. You will either need to work with the XAML GridView, design your own XAML control, or look into vendors/projects that support such controls. That said, you may need to approach the problem with a different philosophy. Instead of trying to implement the same solution in both Windows Forms and Windows Store Apps, try to think of a better way to present and edit grid-like data that will be acceptable to desktops, tablets, and different visual perspectives.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321276/how-to-build-my-own-datagrid-for-win8-app-store/18321887#18321887

Answer (score 0):

Datagridview is not supported in Metro App . Instead you should try to use GridView to display your data.

Document of GridView : [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx)

Some samples : [Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListViewSimple-d5fc27dd)