# How to build my own DataGrid for Win8 App Store?

Tags: windows-8, windows

I have a list of items that I want to display in a table-like control, for my Win8 app store. Lets say that the object Item contains a Barcode, price and amount (all are double types). I want to present a table with different columns for each prop of this object. I would also like to present this table in a LayoutAwarePage. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can start from here : [How to get a data grid like UI for a collection of Items?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikezh/archive/2012/07/26/windows-8-metro-app-how-to-get-a-data-grid-like-ui-for-a-collection-of-items.aspx)

[MyToolkit - DataGrid](http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DataGrid)

Usage of MyToolkit DataGrid

```xml
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="dg">
    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"  />
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection<viewModel> People = new ObservableCollection<viewModel>
    {
        new viewModel("fname", "lname"),
        new viewModel("fname", "lname"),
        new viewModel("fname", "lname"),
        new viewModel("fname", "lname")
    };

    dg.ItemsSource = People;
}

public class viewModel
{
    public viewModel(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This ToolKit is very nice, But when I add the control DataGrid from it I get an exception on the spot. Know how to solve this?

Comment: Post some details about the exception.

Comment: It goes like that:COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Comment: Just a simple xaml use of the control: <ToolKit:DataGrid></Tollkit:DataGrid>.

Comment: How did you pass the `ItemSource` ? Why you didn't declare columns ? Empty `<ToolKit:DataGrid></ToolKit:DataGrid>` will throw that error.

Comment: I tried your code and it didn't work. Please notice that I want to use this control for a Win8 app store, and that this control is located on a LayoutAwarePage. I tried exactly your code - and all I saw was a gray rectangle, nothing on it.

Comment: can you please send me your project ?

Comment: Please send me and email, and i will replay with my project. I can't send you mail directly for some reason...

Comment: bravo123@bezeqint.net

Comment: I played with this control and now I can see the text of the objects in my list. How do I make the background of each cell in the Datagrid be in a different color?

Comment: Better you post that query in a separate question with what you've tried so far to get different color.

Comment: Does it support "AutoGenerateColumns"?